# How to stream sharded MySQL Tables CDC to Kafka Cluster

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, cdc

I have new **shared MySQL tables** being created every day with names as **"output_table_[date]"**.
I want to **capture CDC** from it and stream to my **Kafka cluster**, so what can I use for that?

I explored Debezium connector for MySQL, but couldn't find any configuration which can take into account the new tables created everyday. eg. while creating the connector we have to provide “table.whitelist” for the tables we would like to capture CDC for, but in my case of new tables being created everyday, we'll have to manually update that everyday.

So can anyone help me with possible solutions to my use case?

Comment: table.whitelist (table.include.list) is optional parameter. I think you also have to setup [Schema history topic](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-schema-history-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture *all* tables by simply omitting `table.include.list` and related options (btw. your usage of `table.whitelist` indicates you're using an older version of Debezium). Note for Debezium 1.6 we're also planning to do a PoC for supporting changes to the filter configuration.